# How to get the raw query and the list of columns from an Eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

Is it possible in Laravel, using eloquent to get the raw SQL query generated by the ORM query ?

Also, is it possible to get an array of all the columns involved in that query ?

Consider for exemple that Eloquent query:

```
$query = Category::join('posts', 'post.category_id', '=', 'category.id');
```

Would it be possible to retrieve in the code, the raw SQL of that query, and most importantly, an array of the columns involved ? In this cas, the columns of the Category and the Post models (category.id, category.name, post.id, post.title, post.category_id, etc...)

Comment: you mean the last query executed by this ORM? or you mean the value from these columns?

Comment: I mean the name of the columns used in the SELECT statement of that query. I presume it will be SELECT * , so I would like the names of all those columns in an array

Answer (score 1):

You can enable ORM logging with:

```php
DB::enableQueryLog();
// query
```

and when your query executed you can get it with:

```php
DB::getQueryLog();
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I get the name of the columns used in the SELECT statement of that query. I presume it will be SELECT * , so I would like the names of all those columns in an array. Is it possible ?

Comment: Yeah sure, you can use Schema::getColumnListing($table); to get table columns.
$table is String of table name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toSql()` and `getBindings()` and  for query builder same as:

```
$sql = $query->toSql();

$bindings = $query->getBindings();
```

If you do not provide any fields it will default to `*`